# What is a word for partaking in art?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the complement of "to create art". I'm trying to describe the act of being affected by it, or by "receiving" it. Specifically, I want to fill in the blank for the following sentence:

> I want to create art that I also enjoy ***_*__**.

So far, the best I have is "consuming". However, I do not like that, as it implies the destruction of the art in the process, which often does not apply. Similarly, I rejected "receiving" as it implies an exchange.

I want to stay away from visually-biased words like "seeing", "viewing", or "observing", as much art is not visual. (Think music, food, etc.)

I struggled with "partaking" for the title; I think it's not at all what I want. It also implies activity; what I want is a bit more passive than that.
"Appreciating" is often used in this context, but I find that very awkward, especially when partnered with it's near-synonym "enjoy". I don't find that it conveys my intent well.
Simply leaving it as "[…] that I also enjoy" isn't ideal either; I want to emphasize the dichotomy with the creation, which is also enjoyable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is subjective. How could you foresee the type of art you want to consume? Shouldn't you appreciate art that surprises you?

Comment: I'm really just concerned with the proper English usage, not the reasonableness of the statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about *[experiencing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/experience?region=us)*? An *experience* is

> an event or occurrence that leaves an impression on someone

So it can describe the act of being moved by any piece of art--be it food, music, visual, or something else.

Answer (score 18):

Generally I think appreciate is used in this context, but without coupling it to "enjoy" since as you mention "appreciate" rather implies enjoyment already.

> I want to create art that I also *appreciate*.

If you are determined to keep the "enjoy" in the sentence, you might say

> I want to create art that I also enjoy [*reveling in*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revel).

Answer (score 9):

"Experiencing" seems extremely suitable to me.

Comment: Agh, 38 seconds after @simchona posted it!

Answer (score 7):

I want to create art that I can **immerse** myself in.

I want to create art that I can **engage** in.

Comment: Engaging is really a versatile word.

Answer (score 5):

`"Value"` may be the type of passive expression you are looking for.

> regard something highly: to regard something as important or useful

Though the phrase would  be

> I want to create art that I also value.

You could also go with

> I want to create are that I also find **pleasing**.

Enjoy is an active word so it will be difficult to enjoy ___ing something passively.

Answer (score 1):

*Aesthetically* may fit your sentence though I realize it does not answer the question.

Comment: Actually that does work reasonably well... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* on an appropriately exalted plane, considering your question, but the word that came to mind for me was **dig**.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"Dabbling in an art" seems appropriate, but may be considered slightly deprecating.

Comment: +1 for "Dabbling".  In my opinion, it is indeed (politely) depreciating, and wholly appropriate until mastery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *patronize* is the word you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with these, but I am not sure if they will fit in.

> ***savour***, ***relish***, ***taste***, ***revel in***

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, "[ingest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingest)"? It is a little figurative, but I have heard it used often before.